# Alterar una columna, para cambiar "nulo" a "no nulo", cuando no se conoce el tipo de datos

Tags: sql-server, null, ddl, alter-table, alter-column

I need to allow nulls in a column, but I don't know its data type. In **oracle** its possible to do this:

```
alter table MyTable modify MyField null;
```

the **SQL server** homologous statement requires the data type (in this example **INT**):

```
alter table MyTable alter column MyField int null;
```

Is there a way to do it like Oracle does?. The idea is not to have to go to the data dictionary to consult the types and build the sentence

Thanks,

Comment: Short answer - there is no similar shortcut to altering a column in this manner.

Comment: Can you please translate the title to English? stackoverflow.com is an English only site.

Comment: I can't editing post: tittle syas: "Altering a column, to change "null" to "not null", when the data type is not known"